# Cast Array<Any> to Array<Int> in Swift

Tags: swift

I have array of Any objects called timestamps, in which first object is string, and rest objects are Int. What i want is, to drop first element and treat rest of array as Array of Int objects..

I tried:

```
let timestamps = xAxisData.dropFirst()
if let timestamps = timestamps as? Array<Int> { 
}
```

It compile, but it says - `Cast from 'ArraySlice<Any>' to unrelated type 'Array<Int>' always fails`

I could possibly iterate through array and create new temporary array with check every element whether it Int or not, but i think there is a better cleaner way?

Comment: "in which first object is string, and rest objects are Int." This indicates you've used the wrong datatype. You meant to use a `struct Timestamps { let something: String; values: [Int] }` here, not an [Any]. Building things on Any is going to bite you again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an `Array` from the `ArraySlice` created by `dropFirst`.

```
let timestamps = Array(xAxisData.dropFirst())
if let timestamps = timestamps as? [Int] { 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use something like a flatMap so no matter were the non-Int values are in the array they are not consider for the resulting array.

```
let originalArray:[Any] = ["No int", 2, 3, "Also not int", 666, 423]
let intArray:[Int] = originalArray.flatMap { $0 as? Int }
print(intArray)
```

Will print this:

> [2, 3, 666, 423]

So in your case you could do something like:

```
let timestamps = xAxisData.flatMap { $0 as? Int }
```

As stated by Steve Madsen in the comment below, if you are using Swift 4.1 or newer Apple suggest to used `compactMap` for getting rid of optional nils so that specific use of `flatMap` is deprecated.

```
let timestamps = xAxisData.compactMap { $0 as? Int }
```

Comment: Swift 4.1 deprecated the use of `flatMap` in favor of `compactMap` to remove optionals from a sequence.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I edited the answer to add your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method to convert a subset of an array with mixed types to something more specific:

```
let intArray = anyArray.compactMap { $0 as? Int }
```

Comment: not really efficient because i know that first element will be string, your solution is O(n) complexity.

Comment: True; for your specific use case @rmaddy's solution is more appropriate. In terms of your question's title, though, a more general solution should be useful to others.

Comment: An `as?` cast on an array is O(n) anyway since it has to check every element